# Spark tries to connect to localhost instead of configured servers

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

This error information shows up:

> Error in query: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Got exception: java.net.ConnectException Call From undefined.hostname.localhost/192.168.xx.xxx to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused);

I don't understand why I will visit the localhost:9000, the host in my core-site.xml is hdfs://192.168.xx.xx:9000, why did I visit localhost:9000
Is it the default host?

Comment: Please show your `/etc/hosts` file content

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 192.168.60.194 hadoop00
192.168.60.168 hadoop01
192.168.60.172 hadoop02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,go to the mysql command line，drop the database(metastore) which you set in your hive-site.xml.

Then,change dictory to the $HIVE_HOME/bin,execute schematool -initSchema -dbType mysql, and the problem is solved.the error due to the metastore in mysql is too late(I have set the metastore in standby environments),I turn to the cluster environment later, but the metastore is previous, so I can create table in hive,not in sparksql.

Thank someone who helps me.@Ravikumar,@cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that hive-site.xml is present in your spark config directory **/etc/spark/conf/** and configure the hive configuration settings.

```
## core-site.xml 
fs.defaultFS

## Hive config 
hive.metastore.uris
```

Comment: I don't find the property named fs.defaultFS in my config and the hive.metastore.uris is not settled .And how I set hive.metastore.uris and fs.defaultFS.

Thank you,SatckOverFlow is amazing,soon reply my question.

Comment: Please edit your other answer, instead of posting two

Answer (score 0):

In hive-site.xml, you can configure the as follows. Please configure your hive meta-store details.

```
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://ip-xx.xx.xx.xx:8020</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
<value>thrift://ip-xx.xx.xx:9083</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>

<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastorecreateDatabase
IfNotExist=true</value>
<description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
<description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hive</value>
<description>user name for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>123456</value>
<description>password for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I can query, delete the table, but I can't create table.when I create table,it errors the same issue

Comment: could you please provide the full stack trace message

Comment: spark-sql> create table t(name string);
           18/02/01 09:26:00 INFO execution.SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: create table t(name string)
Error in query: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Got exception: java.net.ConnectException Call From hadoop00/192.168.60.194 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused);

Answer (score 0):

Your error is related to HDFS, not Hive or SparkSQL

You need to ensure that your `HADOOP_HOME` or `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` are correctly setup in the `spark-env.sh`  if you would like to connect to the correct Hadoop environment rather than use the defaults.

Comment: I already export HADOOP_HOME and HADOOP_CONF_DIR in my spark-env.sh.

Comment: export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.8
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.4
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=hadoop00
export SPARK_LAUNCH_WITH_SCALA=0
export SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH=${SPARK_HOME}/jars
export SCALA_LIBRARY_PATH=${SPARK_HOME}/lib
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=18080

if [ -n "$HADOOP_HOME" ]; then
  export SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH=$SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH:${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native
fi
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.4/etc/hadoop

Comment: I can insert data into the hive warehouse by sparksql.it turns out that the hdfs is right.but I can't understand why I visit the localhost:9000 when I create table by sparksql.

Answer (score 0):

I reset the metastore in Mysql. I use the localhost in my core-site.xml at that time, I init my metastore.So I reset the metastore, and the problem solved.

Comment: You should provide the steps you followed to do this so it can help others